# css selector specificity within bootstrap not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having this markup :

```
<section id="home" class="spacing"> 

<div class="container">
<div class="row">...SOME CONTENT...</div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row full">...SOME CONTENT...</div>
</div>

</section>
```

And I want to remove the `row` margins without overriding the default bootstrap styles, I've added a class `full`.

I've tried this `.row.full {margin-left:0 !important; margin-right:0 !important;}` also `.full` and none of these are working.

If I try `#home .row` is working but I don't want this.

**These are the default styles for row class:
`.row {margin-right:-15px;margin-left:-15px;`**
Why is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: *without overriding the default bootstrap styles* **so what's** `.row.full {margin-left:0 !important; margin-right:0 !important;}` ?

Comment: I've edited my question with the default styles of row class. Please take a look now.

Comment: Given the default styles example, the `.row.full` selector would take precedence, even without `!important`. Something else is going on, maybe something like a syntax error on the line before? http://jsfiddle.net/A84n5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running Twitter-Bootstrap in a client right now and I did this to try it out and it worked fine

```
.row-full {
    margin: 0;
}
```

THen obviously, replace the class name in the div

p.s. any custom stylesheet you run, must be declared under the bootstrap.css in the head,so that it actually overrides bootstrap. Check that as well

Comment: no kidding! change class name from row full to row-full. So instead of using two classes, consolidate into one class only. What he needs is simple, no need to run two classes